# Why are aggregates not allowed in SQL where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, having-clause

```
SELECT SUM(salary) 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE SUM(salary) > 10000;
```

causes error, I know that it needs to be put in `HAVING` clause.

My question is why? As in root cause for this syntax choice in SQL language design.

Comment: Regardless of the syntax your query doesn't make sense. What would that query return? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The query was for example only. Not a real one, just to explain my question better rather than have some say "just use having"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where clause filters rows in the query (*Before* they are aggregated).

Having clause filters rows *after* they have been aggregated.

i.e. Sum, Avg, Count, Max, Min, or any *aggregate* functions are always in a HAVING filter.

'Row based filtering' is performed in the where clause.

This is generally covered in standard SQL basics so you may want to read some background as this could help you.